# Extract xml data from non xml format

Tags: xml, regex

I have a file with a lot of junk data from which I would like to extract some proper formatted XML.

The bit I like to extract is this:

```
<random stuff....;'/>
<GET_FW_VERSION
   FIRMWARE_VERSION = "1.77"
   FIRMWARE_DATE = "Apr 23 2009"
   MANAGEMENT_PROCESSOR = "iLO2"
   LICENSE_TYPE = "iLO 2 Advanced"
    />
more non xml stuff
```

So I want to just take out the `<GET_FW_VERSION>`

I used to do this like so:

```
string FW_VERSION = Regex.Match(result, "<GET_FW_VERSION>.*</GET_FW_VERSION>", RegexOptions.Singleline).ToString();
```

but this does not end in `</GET_FW_VERSION>`

Is there another way to write that regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as long as none of the attribute values contain the sequence "/>".

```
string FW_VERSION = Regex.Match(result, 
   "<GET_FW_VERSION.*/>|<GET_FW_VERSION.*>.*</GET_FW_VERSION>", 
   RegexOptions.Singleline).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

note that `.` in regex means:

> ***`.`***
>   Wildcard: Matches any single character except `\n`

try to use this regex:

```
(?:<GET_FW_VERSION[^>]*>|<GET_FW_VERSION[^>]*>.*</GET_FW_VERSION>)
```

explaination:

> **`|`**
>   Matches any one element separated by the vertical bar `|` character.
>
> ***`[^character_group]`***
>   Negation: Matches any single character that is not in `character_group`.
>
> ***`(?:subexpression)`***
>   Defines a noncapturing group.

Comment: When `RegexOptions.SingleLine` is used, `.` also matches `\n`.